# Android layout.xml UI gone when I use material TabLayout with items

Tags: android, user-interface, android-tablayout

Here is the error:

```xml
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.setTheme(android.content.res.Resources$Theme)" because "ta" is null
    at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:74)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1631)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:874)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3965)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTextAppearance(AppCompatTextView.java:216)
    at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.setTextAppearance(MaterialTextView.java:106)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3954)
    at androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(TextViewCompat.java:289)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.updateTab(TabLayout.java:2772)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:2801)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:2713)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:1673)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:956)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addTabFromItemView(TabLayout.java:824)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addViewInternal(TabLayout.java:1730)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addView(TabLayout.java:1720)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:727)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:884)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:293)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Material components dependency version: `com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0`

Answer (score 2):

So apparently it is a bug that still needs to be addressed, the tablayout will show perfectly on the device/emulator, it just won't show in your design view in the xml file. so no issues with the tablayout itself just with the rendering of it in the design view. You're gonna have to run the app each time you make a change to check it out in this case which is really a big time waster but that's all we can do about it for now.

EDIT:

I actually figured something out about it now, apparently the issue is only present when you add a tabItem into the tabLayout.
so you could comment out all your tabItems, do your work, comment them back in and run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Update dependency of material to
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material'` in **build.gradle** worked for me

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0' 
The latest still have the same issue